# Reading properties of undefined error with WithNextRouter and Storybook

Tags: next.js, storybook

I got "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')" using WithNextRouter in story.

```
export default {
  component: Navbar,
  title: "Components/Navbar",
  decorators: [
    withNextRouter,
    (story) => (
      <div
        className="bg-white w-full relative overflow-hidden"
        style={{ height: "4000px" }}
      >
        {story()}
      </div>
    ),
  ],
};
```

Do I even need it to be in export? If I remove withNextRouter then everything works. However, component uses Link from "next/link" and to mock router I believe storybook needs this decorator.